# Is it possible to have SPA authentication without redirecting to an outside login page

Tags: authentication, single-page-application, identityserver3, openid-connect, identityserver4

I am currently developing an SPA application that connects to a bunch of webAPI's. These API require that the user is logged in, so I started digging into Openid Conect and OAuth2 examples, mostly using IdentityServer.

They all require, for SPA reasons, that the implicit grant should be used for retrieving access_tokens. Token refreshes are handled connecting to authentication server using hidden iframe.

What I understand from this approach o renewing your access_token is that, sessions is maintained at authentication service. Hidden iframe goes to the authentication server, sessions is still active, new access_token is provided.

All that looks good for me, except (for UX reasosn) the fact that my user needs to be redirected to authentication server page for providing credentials.

Isn't it possible to have my SPA application send credentials to authentication server, getting the access_token, and then do the refresh using the hidden iframe for silently renewing (we, obviously dont want the user to keep informing credentials every 15 minutes or every hour..).

If this is not acceptable for security reasons, could you please explain why?

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is possible with "[resource owner password flow](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#resource-owner-password)", but in that model identity provider can not trust your application and will not create a session for your user (to use silent renew later on). Thus such non-interactive approach is not truly SSO. 
For 2019 the recommended flow for any web app such as Angular SPA is Code flow with PKCE extension, as described [here](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Angular/Migrating-oidc-client-js-to-use-the-OpenID-Connect-Authorization-Code-Flow-and-PKCE) or [there](https://damienbod.com/2019/01/09/securing-angular-applications-using-the-openid-connect-code-flow-with-pkce/).

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT:**
Editing this answer to correctly reflect the requirement.

If the requirement is not to show authentication server page and use your own SPA, the only possible way to do it is using "Resource owner password flow" [with the constraints mentioned in the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55417058/1371639)

This is discouraged for two reasons:

- **Security** - Will the SPA have the same security controls as the "Authentication server" has in handling passwords of the user. Right from collection to management of the user password (safely securing for future calls ?). This will massively impact the scope of SPA and it is one of the main reasons why people prefer federated logins (outsourcing login complexity to the third party - in your case authentications server)
- **Trust** - How would you convince the user to handout the "authentication server" password to a relatively new SPA app. Imagine if Google / Facebook allows this pattern for a SPA to collect password instead of redirecting to the Google / Facebook login page. This is a recipe for disaster.

<s>This is exactly what oidc-client-js library does. Have a look at [automaticSilentRenew](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki) settings in their wiki page. Understandably this only works as long as the session at the authentication server is still active.</s>

Comment: Using oidc-client-js library does not require you to use ImplicitFlow? As I understand, using this kind of flow requires the user to be redirected to a login page hosted at IdentityServer. I was trying to achieve a behaviour where I can input user/password inside the Angular application.

Comment: You will still need to use Implicit flow with oidc-client-js. For the first time when a user tries to access protected SPA, the user will be prompted for authentication. For the subsequent Access-Token expiry, the library will initiate a silent access token renewal call (i.e. it will request for a new access token few seconds/minutes before current token expires). So the user won't be prompted for authentication every time the access token expires. Storing user credentials / Client credentials in SPA is not safe since they are exposed publicly

Comment: "the user will be prompted for authentication", that sounds like "the user will be redirected to identity provider login page" which is exactly what the question author seems to be trying to avoid

Comment: Agree! overlooked the requirement - thank you for pointing out