# Use angular 4 login form to authenticate the app with IdentityServer 4

Tags: angular, identityserver4, openid-connect

Is there a way to use a login form from my angular 4 application and post to the identityserver 4 project in order to authenticate the Angular app.

I'm using oidc-client in the Angular app

Actually, to authenticate the Angular App, the user is redirect to the Identity Server 4 project where the login form is sit, then return back to the angular app with the token. This token is saved and used to call Web API application.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Here is the **[`project`](https://github.com/elanderson/Angular-Core-IdentityServer)** to get started with. Also read the related [`documentation`](https://elanderson.net/category/identityserver/). https://github.com/damienbod/AspNet5IdentityServerAngularImplicitFlow I think the documentation links provided there are enough to get started

Answer (score 1):

Below is my answer to [the same question asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45817432/):

Technically it is possible with "[resource owner password flow](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#resource-owner-password)", but in that model identity provider can not trust your application and will not create a session for your user. Thus such non-interactive approach is not truly SSO. 
For 2019 the recommended flow for any web app such as Angular SPA is Code flow with PKCE extension, as described [here](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Angular/Migrating-oidc-client-js-to-use-the-OpenID-Connect-Authorization-Code-Flow-and-PKCE) or [there](https://damienbod.com/2019/01/09/securing-angular-applications-using-the-openid-connect-code-flow-with-pkce/).

Answer (score 0):

By the time you may have found out how, but I'll show my solution for others.
Identity providers only send you to a login page if you are not logged in! so you if you are connecting in through a SPA (e.g. Angular) you need to log in before calling oidc-client's API. You simply send an Http request to login action of the Identity provider and it will issue a sign-in cookie, then you call authorize endpoint (oidc-client's API) and it will not show a login page anymore.
You can also set the login path in your Identity Server to the location of your login page in the angular app and this will send unauthenticated users to the angular app login page instead of its own login page.